# How to make a switch for locales using Appaccelerator?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I have an iPhone/ Android app built using Appaccelerator. I have translated all text by placing it into locales (i18n//strings.xml) ,and I have also implemented a switch :

```
<label for="flip-1" class="username">Language:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">EN</option>
    <option value="on">NL</option>
</select>
```

which works reasonably well on Android and iPhone.

How can I enable this select element to update active language locale within the app, so the language of the application would change, and is this possible without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change current locale in runtime. Locale depends on current language of a cell phone, but you can still do some work around.
Create strings.xml file in your i18n directory and put all your texts there like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="en_car">Car</string>
    <string name="de_car">Auto</string>
</resources>
```

The you can implement your own `L()` function:

```
Ti.App.defaultLang = "en"; // global variable with default language (set it in app.js)
function myL(str, lang) {
    if(lang && str) {
        return L(lang + '_' + str);
    } else {
        return L(Ti.App.defaultLang + '_' + str);
    }
}
```

I haven't test it, just want to give you some example to deal with it. You can maybe pass also hint option like in Ti docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Locale-method-getString

Comment: This is very similar to the way I have it implemented at the moment, with only difference, that I use default L() function. What I cannot seem to crack, is how to influence the language within the .html files that I use for layouts.